# Put a =SUM formula in the "value_if_false"

Tags: excel-formula

This is my first question posted so please bear with me.

I am trying to have the `value_if_false` run as a `=sum formula`. Here is what i have.

`Cell B23=0 or 500`, if it is zero the true value will read "" <-- black cell. But if the value is `500` i need the false value to show `=sum(b23-(e23*.20))`.

My Formula:

`=IF(B23=0,"","=sum(b23-(e23*.20))"`

False value only returns the equation. Is there a way to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: remove the double-quotes and the `=` from your value-if-false expression. The quotes instruct Excel to take it as literal text. The `=` is only for the beginning of the whole formula, not for nested expressions inside it.

Comment: Result is `=IF(B23=0,"",SUM(B23-(E23*0.2)))`.

Comment: Or if you want the false to literally show the formula then your quote is just a little off.. `=IF(B23=0,"","=SUM(B23-(E23*0.2))")`

Comment: well .. sum of a single value seems unusual `=IF(B23, B23 - E23 / 5, "")`

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about checking for two conditions B23=0 and B23=500 (at least that is how I read it - apologies if not) then this should work:

```
=IF(B23=0,"X",IF(B23=500,SUM(B23-(E23*0.2)),"check"))
```

You can replace "check" with whatever, so if B23 is 245 etc.